# Why does IQueryable.Select use the same reference for each iteration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, iqueryable

I've got an `IQueryable` on which I want to execute a `Select`. In that select I create a new instance of an object and run a function which copies the values of the object form the IQueryable(b) to to newly created object(new DTO) and then returns this instance.

IQueryable.Select:

```
businessLayer.GetAll().Select( b => new DTO().InitInhertedProperties(b)).ToList();
```

Function in DTO:

```
public DTO InitInhertedProperties(Base baseInstance)
{
    return Utilities.InitInhertedProperties(this, baseInstance);
}
```

Function for Copying:

```
public static T InitInhertedProperties<T,K>(T instance, K baseClassInstance)  where T : K
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in baseClassInstance.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(baseClassInstance, null);
        if (null != value) propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, value, null);
    }

    return instance;
}
```

The first time the `InitInhertedProperties` method gets called `instance` is an empty object, `baseClassInstance` has the values that it should have:

[image]

The result of the first iteration looks like this:
[image]

As you see: Everything worked out like it should be on the first iteration. Now the second iteration.

The second time the `InitInhertedProperties` method gets called `insatnce` isn't a new instance, but the one of the first iteration. The `baseClassInstance` is exactly what it should be:

[image]

The result of the second iteration looks like this:
[image]

The resulting list looks like this:
[image]

This only happens when using `IQueryable.Select`. When using `List.Select` the result looks just like expected.

That means doing this fixed the issue. But it's just a work around not the solution.

```
businessLayer.GetAll().ToList().Select( b => new DTO().InitInhertedProperties(b)).ToList();
```

Comment: I think your problem is somewhere else than in the code you posted ... What is businessLayer.GetAll() doing? Returns an IQueryable? From EF or ... ?

Comment: Yes it it does return a IQueryable from EF!
Doing this:
businessLayer.GetAll().ToList().Select( b => new DTO().InitInhertedProperties(b)).ToList();
Fixed the error.. But thats just a workaround and not the solution.

Comment: Then this is the unclear part for me because if this method returned an IQueryable for an unexecuted "Linq to Entities"-query you should get an NotSupportedException exception actually ...  Because InitInhertedProperties is not known in Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you working with `IQueryable` you are bound to Expressions. Entity Framework will inspect each expression that you put inside `Select`, `OrderBy` and other methods and try to translate it to SQL. So you can't call arbitrary methods inside your lambda, only known by EF

If you want to do something, that does not have a direct support from SQL engine you can call `AsEnumerable`:

```
businessLayer.GetAll().AsEnumerable().Select( ...
```

(Please note, that `AsEnumerable` is better than `ToList` because it keep laziness)

---

Another option that *may* (or may not, depending on Query Provider version) work is to build expression manually:

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, TDto>> InitInhertedProperties<TEntity, TDto>() where TDto : TEntity
{
    var entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BusinessObject), "b");
    var newDto = Expression.New(typeof(Dto).GetConstructors().First());
    var body = Expression.MemberInit(newDto,
        typeof(TDto).GetProperties()
            .Select(p => Expression.Bind(p, Expression.Property(entity, p.Name)))
      );

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TDto>>(body, entity);
}
```

Usage:

```
var myExp = InitInhertedProperties<BusinessObject, Dto>();
var result = businessLayer.GetAll().Select(myExp).ToList();
```